# how can i run gradel sync at android studio?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

my version is 4.0 but i don't see gradel sync  icon or button

how can i find it??

these are my screen

when i google it there are button or icon but i don't have...

[image]

[image]

where should i find it?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the project structure view - Android.
   [screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtErF.png)
2. In the project structure panel, Gradle Scripts/build.gradle file click.
   [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHkiL.png)
3. If you change code or not match the gradle version, you can see the alert above code editor.
   [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxxjU.png)

Another you can find here.
File/Settings/Keymap/Plug-ins/Android/Sync Project with gradle files
And then double-click on it to Add Keyboard Shortcut, setting shortcut.
[screen4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DbrV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Open your gradle. properties file in Android Studio.
Add the following line to the file: ...
Restart Android Studio for your changes to take effect.
Click Sync Project with Gradle Files to sync your project.
or manually
File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Plugins -> Android Support -> Sync Project with gradle files (Right click on it to add keyboard shortcut) -> Apply -> OK